# SSL equivalent of givedescriptor() and takedescriptor()

Tags: ssl, ibm-midrange

I am converting an old tcp only server to use SSL (via IBM's GSkit), and one of the problems is getting the SSL handle into the spawned program. The original code passes the raw socket in via calls to the `givedescriptor()` and then uses `takedescriptor()` to get and then use the passed in socket.

Is there a GSKit/SSL equivalent of the give/take descripter methods?

[givedescriptor()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/apis/gvsoc.htm) API documentation

**UPDATE:**

The issue is that the socket and the SSLHandle are created in one process, which initialized the SSL environment, and then need to be passed on to another process entirely - hence the need to give/take descriptor, as the socket / SSLHandle need to 'given' to the new process (it is actually an RPG program that is submitted and runs independently from the original program).

**UPDATE 2:**

Looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312436/adapting-current-socket-server-design-to-ssl-c-gsk-spawnp), so I'll have a read of that as well.

From the other article (which doesn't have a code based answer, but a written solution)

> "It looks like the session handles are just pointers to some storage
>   in heap. Due to the design of Single Level Store, you could copy them
>   via shared memory (memmap, shmget/shmat, ...). You just have to ensure
>   that the process that opened the GSK environment doesn't die or the
>   activation group will get cleaned up and those pointers will become
>   invalid. You also will probably need to put a mutex or some other
>   locking primitive around them if you're going to have multiple threads
>   accessing the shared data structure."

**UPDATE 3:**

This is the example I am using to share the memory between processes - [Example: Using semaphore set and shared memory functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/apiref/apiexusmem.htm), still not exactly solved the issue yet though.

**UPDATE 4:**

I thought I'd add more details of why I need to ask the question. I am changing a non-blocking TCP server that is used as a connection point to an IBM i. It has the 'standard' mechanism for handling connections as they come it, creating threads and negotiating the connections in these threads. The threads then create independent process (via `sbmjob`). In the vanilla TCP version we can then give the running job the handle of the socket via the `give/takedescriptor` function, and will merrily write to and from the socket.

So I need an equivalent way of getting the independently running program to be able to write to SSL.

It maybe that this is not possible with the current mechanism.

Comment: Here is a list of the GSKit API's:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzab6/cgskit.htm  Can you use [gsk_environment_open](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/apis/gsk_environment_open.htm) to get a handle to pass around and then use the handle with API's like [gsk_attribute_get_cert_info](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/apis/gsk_attribute_get_cert_info.htm).

Comment: Have you tried using the give & take descriptor API's with a SSL connection? Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: The calls to `gsk_secure_soc_read` need a `gsk_handle`, and this is setup in the original program, and needs to get into the final program, _somehow_..

Comment: Seems like it would be easier and a lot more reliable and stable to just run the plaintext TCP application behind [an SSL reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

Comment: The issue is that there is no such thing as an 'SSL handle'. It will inevitably be a *pointer* into some opaque data structure in the *originating process*, as SSL is an application layer protocol. So you can't 'give' an 'SSL handle' to another process and expect it to work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an 'SSL handle' known to the operating system and inheritable by child processes or transferable to other processes. The 'SSL handle' will inevitably be a *pointer* into some opaque data structure *in the originating process,* as SSL is an application layer protocol, and therefore implemented in the process, not in the kernel. So you can't 'give' an 'SSL handle' to another process and expect it to work.

**EDIT**

> The answers here don't really answer the underlying question, which how I should do this, so although the bounty has been awarded, I can't accept the only answer.

The answer is that you *can't* do it.

> It maybe that this is not possible with the current mechanism.

Correct. As you've foreseen this possiblity in your question, it is difficult to understand why you can't accept it in an answer.

Answer (score -1):

In principle your idea is not impossible! If you believe that is possible try to find the answer!

If all answerer from the SO will say that is impossible it is not all time the true!

> **For example:** 15 years ago I had tried to find the answer how can I write an Java-applet which can write and read images on a server.
>   Everybody had said to me that is impossible, but I did not believed it. I
>   tried to find my answer again and again. And I had found the answer: I
>   disassembled one online apllet from one specialist and in the source
>   code I find my answer: using PHP server we can do it. I asked the
>   owner from this applet about details of communication between
>   Java-applet and PHP server and he has helped me.

You have to find your specialist. That is the first rule to find the correct answer. May be on the IBM forum you will find someone.

The second rule is to read a lot of books from specialist about this. Not only one book. May be three of them or more.

I would recommend you also to read **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, because in your question you do not have any computer language. And I think we have on SO someone specialist which could give you the correct answer.

The first rule on SO for finding of correct specialist is to set the correct tags. Without correct tags only few people see your question and it is only question of luck that somebody from them is the correct specialist for you.

Be optimistic and try to believe in you! Good luck and success!

[image]

Comment: Optimism is lovely but it doesn't make square circles possible.